# How to transfer part of an array to another? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to transfer `spl[i]` to `spp[k]` if it has `(`.  However, I get:

```
Cannot set property 'k' of undefined
```

Can I even set `spp[i]` to `spl[i]?`

Note: the snippet will only log on the console.

```
var spl= ['Mozilla/5.0 ','(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; X64)',' AppleWebKit/537.36 ','(KHTML& Like Gecko)',' Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36']
var spp= [a,b];
var l= 0, k= 0;
while(typeof spl[l]== 'string'){
    if (spl[l].includes('(')){
        spp[k]=spl[l];
        ++k;
    }
    ++l;
}
console.log('spp='+spp);
```

I want spp to be ['(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; X64)','(KHTML& Like Gecko)']
Note the & is a temporary comma as .toString uses commas.

Comment: Your first code is not correct. `spl` is not an array

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that; however, it still does not work after it is fixed as in the snippet.

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale Your first snippet is working fine: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agmsovmx/). Also for snippet 2, I'd suggest using smaller functions to make code more reusable

Comment: what should the whole code do? i bet i can shortify it alot

Comment: another err: *var last3= gc4ss.toString;*

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale Whats is the desired output ? It seems that you only want the string that have `(` then you can use `Array#filter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define array as

```
var spl= ['Mozilla/5.0 ','(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; X64)',' AppleWebKit/537.36 ','(KHTML& Like Gecko)',' Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36']
```

Comment: I think that was just an error in my example as I already tested it and they spl is an array.  I just forgot that arrays need '[ ]' also I am new to js.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you , you just want to wrap pharenthesis around if there arent any:

```js
console.log(
  ["a", "b", "(c)"].map(el => el.substr(0, 1) === "(" ? el : "(" + el + ")")
)
//["(a)","(b)","(c)"]
```

http://jsbin.com/reluveroyi/edit?console

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your *HTML/CSS/JS* code and make it executable.

Comment: @Rajesh i cannot. *stack snippets arent available on mobile* , i will do when they implemented it, but i wont switch to my pc just to add snippets everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the string from the previous value was not splitting.  To avoid errors, you should not use `string.split('chr')` instead you should do `string= string.split('chr')`

```
spl= spl.toString();
//console.log(spl);
spl= spl.split(",");
var spp= ['a','b'];
var l= 0, k= 0;
while(typeof spl[l]== 'string'){
    if (spl[l].includes('(')=== true){
        spp[k]= spl[l];
        spl[l]= "()";
        ++k;
    }
    ++l;
}
```